# regex space issue in a text string

Tags: php, regex

My following regex condition works in case when $outputMsg="Center xxx has been updated" but it does not works when $outputMsg="Center xxx yyy has been updated"

```
if(isset($messages->messages['status'])){
       $outputMsg= strip_tags($messages->messages['status'][0]);
       if(preg_match('/^Center [\w\d]+ has been updated.$/', $outputMsg))
       {
           $messages->messages['status'][0]="Centre details successfully updated";
       }
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: try with '/^Center (.*?) has been updated.$/'

Comment: `[\w\d]` the `\d` is useless here since `\w` already matches numbers. So to wrap it up you may use `(\w+\s+)+` for your issue. Ah and the last dot must be escaped `\.`.

Comment: Why do you need to check against 'xxx is updated' if you are not going to use 'xxx' again? Just check against 'has been updated' (no need for regular expressions) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space in your regex, like:

```
/^Center [\w ]+ has been updated.$/
```